# Having trouble using/installing @pnp/sp modules

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm trying to use the attachments module, specifically these features:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/attachments/
I've installed all pnp/sp modules necessary (I think!) using : https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/ as a reference.
Problem is I'm getting a 'cannot find module' for the attachments module. Below are the imports:

```
import { default as pnp } from 'sp-pnp-js';
import { ItemAddResult, Web } from 'sp-pnp-js';
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp"; //this is fine, which suggests it's installed properly?
import { IItem } from '@pnp/sp/attachments'; //cannot find this module
import "@pnp/sp/webs"; 
import "@pnp/sp/lists/web";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import "@pnp/sp/attachments";
```

I've been successfully using pnp.sp features in this particular project so am stumped why I can't import and use the attachments feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an existing project, that you've had for a bit, and you've already got @pnp in the package.json file, it may be you're using version 1 of @pnp, and you are reading the documentation for version 2.

I get the same error cannot find module when I add it to a project @pnp/sp 1.3.7
But don't get it with version 2.0.0

Version 1 document for attachments:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/sp/docs/attachments/

Version 2:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/attachments/

Comment: Additional information based on Joe, the import should be import { IAttachmentInfo } from "@pnp/sp/attachments".

Comment: Thanks - I've updated @pnp/sp to 2.0.0 and the error is gone. I've not got an error on my existing sp.we.lists.getByTitle, under the word web. It says it does not exist on SPRest. I'm sure this is a simple change of syntax now, but what would it be perhaps off the top of your head?

Comment: Above should say 'I've now got an error...'
Anyway, above fixed with help of:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273921/property-web-does-not-exist-on-type-sprest